# JavaScript vs PHP Array Notation

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I'm trying to learn JavaScript arrays, and I'm having trouble duplicating how I've been creating arrays in PHP:

```
$fruits[] = 'banana';
$fruits[] = 'orange';
```

Doing that in PHP automatically gives banana the key of 0 and orange the key of 1. But when I'm trying to do it in JavaScript, it doesn't seem to automatically assign the key:

```
var fruits = [];
fruits[] = 'banana';
fruits[] = 'orange';
```

That doesn't work. But this does:

```
var fruits = [];
fruits[0] = 'banana';
fruits[1] = 'orange';
```

Am I missing something? It seems kind of silly that you'd need to manually create the keys. This notation also seems ok:

```
var fruits = [ 'banana', 'orange' ];
```

But for my purposes, I'm trying to convert a big array from PHP to JavaScript, and life would be much easier if the second example worked. Is my notation slightly off, or are the last two examples the only ways to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "...a big array from PHP to Java,..."
Java?

Comment: If you're generating it in php anyway, it would probably be less client intensive to use your third example to declare fruits.

Comment: @AlexLunix For real? I did not know that. I'll keep that in mind and possibly make edits to the php then. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```
var fruits = [];
fruits.push('banana');
fruits.push('orange');
```

Comment: Perfect! You rock. Thanks for the help xdazz!

Comment: P.S. Thanks to everyone else who replied; you are all right. xdazz was just a little quicker.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you're looking for `array.push(some_element)`

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript and PHP are different languages.  To add a value to end of a JS array, use `.push`.

```
var fruits = [];
fruits.push('banana');
fruits.push('orange');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add items into a JavaScript array, without defining the keys, then do this:

```
var fruits = [];
fruits.push('banana');
fruits.push('orange');
```